# want to add some columns from multiple dataframe into one specific dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

so basically I have downloaded multiple stocks data in and stored in CSV format so I created a function to that and passed a list of stocks name to that user-defined function .so one stock data have multiple columns in like open price, close price etc so I want close price column from every stock df stored in a new data frame with stock names as heading to the columns in new data frame  with their close prices in it

so I created a function to download multiple stocks data and passed a list of stocks names to get  data I wanted and the function stores them in a CSV format 
2) then I tried creating a for loop which reads each and every stock data CSV file and tries to pick only close column from each stock dataframe and store it another empty data frame so i have a data frame of-the stocks close prices with their column header as stock name of the close prices  so i was succesful in dowloading the stocks data but failed in 2 part

```
stocks = ['MSFT','IBM', 'GM', 'ACN', 'GOOG']
end=datetime.datetime.now().date() 
start=end-pd.Timedelta(days=365*5) 

def hist_data(stocks):
    stock_df=web.DataReader(stocks,'iex',start,end)
    stock_df['Name']=stocks
    fileName=stocks+'_data.csv'
    stock_df.to_csv(fileName) 


with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(len(stocks)) as executor:
    result=executor.map(dwnld_data,stocks)
print('completed')

#failing in the code below



close_prices = pd.DataFrame()

for i in stocks:
    df = pd.read_csv(i + '_data.csv')
    df1 = df['close']
    close_prices.append(df1)


#so when I try to print close_prices I get blank output
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
close_prices = pd.DataFrame()

for i in stocks:
    df = pd.read_csv(i + '_data.csv')
    close_prices[i] = df['close']
```

Comment: great it works but a bit confusing as [i] represents each element in list which has some data in it  .using it fo empty list  like close_prices[i] =  df['close'] means we save 'close'  one by one in close_prices

Comment: If the value in ``i`` isn't what you want, you can pick another name for the columns that contain the closing prices.